# CVXPY expression doesn't give expected result

Tags: python, expression, cvxpy

I am using CVXPY (version 1.0). I do not understand what causes the difference between a `ZERO` expression and a `NONNEGATIVE` expression as demonstrated by the following code:

```
>>> import cvxpy as cv
>>> a = cv.Variable(1)
>>> b = cv.Variable(1)
>>> print((cv.square(a-b)*1/(1e-6)).__repr__()) 
Expression(CONSTANT, ZERO, (1,))
>>> print((cv.square(a-b)*float(1/1e-6)).__repr__()) 
Expression(CONVEX, NONNEGATIVE, (1,))
```

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo check the updated question. You have to use `__repr__()` when printing and cvxpy v1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug that is now fixed in 1.0. Small values were being rounded to 0.